# iOS word wrap more evenly?

Tags: ios, uilabel, word-wrap

I have a title that I put into a UILabel. I get it to wrap the text just fine onto two lines, but often the second line just has one small word in it. Is there a way to tell the system to wrap the lines a little more evenly?

The titles are dynamically fetched, so I don't believe I can have this determined ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could figure out what the length would be on a single line, then take that width, divide by 2, and use that result as the width constraint for a 2 line label. That would perhaps get you a better visual result, but you might have to tweak this a little if you have long words that would cause your label to be 3 lines (unless more than 2 lines is ok).

This approach has the disadvantage of doing a little extra work, but it might do the trick. For example:

```
    NSString *text = @"This is my very long title I want evenly on 2 lines";
    UILabel *theLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    theLabel.text = text;
    // ...other label setup here, like font, etc
    [theLabel sizeToFit];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(theLabel.frame.size.width / 2.0, 1000);
    CGSize labelSize = [theLabel.text sizeWithFont:theLabel.font constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    theLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    theLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    CGRect frame = theLabel.frame;
    frame.size = labelSize;
    theLabel.frame = frame;
```

That should do it. Warning: Written from memory. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I went ahead and created a CocoaPod called [EvenlyWrappedLabel](https://cocoapods.org/pods/EvenlyWrappedLabel) that was inspired by Erik van der Neut's answer. It has a few neat features:

1. Prevents single word orphans from taking up the entire bottom line.

   Example:

   ```
   This sentence has a single
   orphan.
   ```

   Becomes:

   ```
   This sentence has
   a single orphan.
   ```
2. Prevents text from grouping up at the top, feeling top heavy.

   Example:

   ```
   This sentence has a lot of words on
   the top line.
   ```

   Becomes:

   ```
   This sentence has a lot
   of words on the top line.
   ```
3. Option to spread text evenly across every line available.

   Example:

   ```
   This only takes up one line.
   ```

   Becomes*:

   ```
   This only
   takes up
   one line.
   ```

   **`numberOfLines = 3`, `useEveryLine = true`*
4. Works with autolayout constraints and respects intrinsic sizing.
5. Extremely easy to integrate, just replace `let label = UILabel()` with `let label = EvenlyWrappedLabel()`.
6. A bad ass example app.

[image: Example Project Screenshot]

If you don't use CocoaPods, you can find the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/StockX/EvenlyWrappedLabel). Enjoy!

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's an easy way of doing this.  There are UIKit additions to `NSString` that allow you to determine the required dimensions to display a string with a particular font.  What you could do is calculate the height necessary using all of the available width, then run the same calculation in a loop, reducing the width until it requires additional vertical space.  Then you use the previous value as the width of the label and align it appropriately.

Comment: If at the given font, the label only takes one line, that's perfectly fine. What I really want to avoid are very topheavy labels where everything but one word is on the top, and then there's one tiny word on the bottom. Basically, the title doesn't have to wrap, but if it's going to wrap, I'd like it to be a little more even.

Comment: Yes, that's what the method I described will do.  Your initial calculation will produce a height that is one line high.  Your loop will exit when it spills over into two lines.  You use the previous value for the width, which is the narrowest width possible that allows the content to stay on one line.

Answer (score 1):

Go from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

**Killing Orphans for Design Points:**
Technically the function doesn't kill orphans (free-floating words like "Soul" and "life" in the top picture), but adjusts each of the rows of words to be as close to a hypothetical mean length as possible. It assumes you have a label already created with text in it.

Here's the code:

```
-(NSString *)killOrphans:(UILabel *)label {

int numberOfLines = [self numberOfLines:label];
UIFont * font = label.font;

float total = 0.0f;
NSMutableArray * widths = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray * splitWords = [label.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
for (int n = 0; n < (int)splitWords.count; n++){
    NSString * word = splitWords[n];
    NSString * spaceWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", word];
    float wordWidth = [spaceWord sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}].width;
    [widths addObject:@(wordWidth)];
    total += wordWidth;
}

total -= 1.0f; //remove last space.
/* might be easier to draw out long UILabel and grab width directly */

float meanLengthPerLine = total / (float)numberOfLines;
NSString * string;
int newLineCount = 0;
meanLengthPerLine -= 1.0f;

do {
    
    newLineCount = 1;
    string = @"";
    meanLengthPerLine += 1.0f;
 
    float runWidth = 0.0f;
    for (int n = 0; n < (int)splitWords.count; n++){
        
        NSString * word = splitWords[n];
        float width = [widths[n] floatValue];
        float potential = runWidth + width;
        if (potential <= meanLengthPerLine){
            string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", string, word];
            runWidth += width;
        } else {
            newLineCount++;
            
            string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", string, word];
            runWidth = width;
        }
    }
    
} while (newLineCount > numberOfLines);

/* can set uilabel.text directly here or return */
return [string substringFromIndex:1]; //Remove first space

}
```

As the the mean width var `meanLengthPerLine` is increased for each line, it creates space in an earlier row to allow the more words to "fold up". If the loop was drawn out it would go from something like a skinny 5 line label to an evenly distributed three line. Here is a high-level of what's happening:

1. Calculate total width of the label text as if it were spelled out on a long `UILabel`.
2. Calculate the mean (divide by number of lines - separate function)
3. Use the mean as your starting point - this is the target width per line.
4. Add words to rows until it breaches the 'mean' threshold.
5. If it breaches, create a new row.
6. If after adding all words, there are more lines than the `UILabel` should have (in the example above the label wants three lines), then increment the mean width a bit and repeat the process. This makes room for that word that was formerly pushed down (because of breach) to now live one row up. In the code above, the length is increased by one pixel `meanLengthPerLine += 1.0f;` but you could save some loops and add 2 or 3 pixels and get to your answer faster, but less accurately, as you wish.
7. Eventually you'll find the 'tightest' mean width for the desired number of lines.

**Calculating Number of Lines Accurately**
Here's the code to accurately calculate the number of lines, as a lot of the existing solutions based on division by line height or whatever include some inaccuracy through rounding / ceil. This codee is longer and more annoying but seems to hold up:

```
-(int)numberOfLines:(UILabel *)label{

NSArray * splitWords = [label.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

int lineCount = 1;
float currentLineWidth = 0.0f;

for (int n = 0; n < (int)splitWords.count; n++){
    
    NSString * word = splitWords[n];
    NSString * spaceWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", word];
    float wordWidth = [spaceWord sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}].width;
    float potentialWidth = currentLineWidth + wordWidth;
    
    if (potentialWidth <= label.frame.size.width){
        
        currentLineWidth = potentialWidth;
        
    } else {
        
        wordWidth = [word sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}].width; //try without the space
        potentialWidth = currentLineWidth + wordWidth;
        
        if (potentialWidth <= label.frame.size.width){
            
            currentLineWidth = potentialWidth;
            
        } else {
            
            lineCount++;
            currentLineWidth = wordWidth;
        }
    }
}

return lineCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a multilingual app I needed this exact same problem fixed as well. The app can show its UI in 9 different languages, and the message lengths vary quite a bit between languages. Because of this I ended up with some unfortunate default word wrapping for some of the multi-line messages. For example, there were several instances where Japanese translations ended up with one full line of text followed by just a character or two on the next line.

I added the following two methods to my Layout Utility class that solved this problem for me (see code below). This solution works for labels with any number of lines (1, 2, 3, more...) and any language. (Change `ECLayoutUtility` to your own class name.)

The basic idea is this:

1. Given a UILabel showing text, detect its current height.
2. Do a binary search for the minimum width for that label that does *not* increase that height.

In my code below, you can control the trade-off between precision and the number of turns through the `while` loop with the `granularity` variable.

Example of a problematic Japanese label before this fix:

[image]

That same Japanese label after the fix:

[image]

These are the two methods I added to my Layout Utility class. I split them up like this, so you can also just enquire to get the new size, in case you are using Autolayout for example, and want to use the size information to manipulate constraints instead of resizing the label itself directly:

```
+ (void)wordWrapEvenlyTextInUILabel:(UILabel *)uiLabel
                        forMaxWidth:(CGFloat)maxLabelWidth
{
    [ECLayoutUtility resizeView:uiLabel
                         toSize:[self getLabelSizeWithMinimumWidthForLabel:uiLabel
                                                               forMaxWidth:maxLabelWidth]];
}


+ (CGSize)getLabelSizeWithMinimumWidthForLabel:(UILabel *)uiLabel
                                   forMaxWidth:(CGFloat)maxLabelWidth
{
    NSLog(@"Current size for label \"%@\" is %@", uiLabel.text, NSStringFromCGSize(uiLabel.frame.size));

    // Start off by determining what height the label would get for the given maximum width:
    CGSize labelSize = [uiLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxLabelWidth, MAXFLOAT)
                                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:uiLabel.font }
                                                  context:nil].size;

    // Constraining the label to that height, now figure out the mimumum width for
    // which this label still shows its text within that given height. We find
    // that height with a binary search for the smallest label width that does
    // not increment the label height.

    CGFloat maxWidth    = maxLabelWidth;
    CGFloat testWidth   = 0.5 * maxWidth;
    CGFloat minWidth    = 0;
    CGFloat granularity = 1;

    while (maxWidth > testWidth + granularity)
    {
        CGFloat newHeight = [uiLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(testWidth, MAXFLOAT)
                                                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                    attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:uiLabel.font }
                                                       context:nil].size.height;

        NSLog(@"H: %.2f, min W: %.2f, mid W: %.2f, max W: %.2f", newHeight, minWidth, testWidth, maxWidth);

        if (newHeight > labelSize.height)
        {
            // Width reduction lead to height increase, so new width is too small.
            // Now set the new width to mid-point between what we just tried and
            // the last known acceptable width:
            minWidth   = testWidth;                         // increase the lower bound
            testWidth += 0.5 * (maxWidth - testWidth);      // increase width for next test
        }
        else
        {
            // Height not affected by the width reduction, so lets try to reduce it even more:
            maxWidth   = testWidth;                         // reduce the upper bound
            testWidth -= 0.5 * (testWidth - minWidth);      // reduce width for next test
        }
    }

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(maxWidth, labelSize.height);
    NSLog(@"New size for label \"%@\" is %@", uiLabel.text, NSStringFromCGSize(newSize));

    return newSize;
}
```

I'm calling the `+wordWrapEvenlyTextInUILabel:forMaxWidth:` method from the `-viewWillLayoutSubviews` in my View Controller as follows:

```
// Make sure that any text in the promo message that is wrapped over multiple lines
// is wrapped evenly, so we don't get very uneven lines that look ugly:
[ECLayoutUtility wordWrapEvenlyTextInUILabel:_promoMessageLabel
                                 forMaxWidth:_promoMessageLabel.frame.size.width];
```

I have tested this for different labels in different languages and it looks to be doing the job perfectly. Here's a Vietnamese example:

[image]

I hope this helps someone else as well :-)

Thanks,

Erik